# How to create a new frame in IE8 using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer-8

I have an html frameset `<frameset name="home" id="home" ...>` and 
I'd like to append a new frame to it using JS. So I wrote this piece of code:

```
var newFrame = document.createElement("frame");
newFrame.id = "myNewFrame";
newFrame.name = "myNewFrame";
newFrame.src = "/myRelativeUrl.html";
var domFrameset = document.getElementById("home");
if (domFrameset) {
    domFrameset.appendChild(newFrame);
}
```

**It works as expected in modern browsers but not in IE8**. It creates the frame tag, but does not perform the request.

Comment: What is `#home`?  Is that a `<frameset>`?  I don't know if you can have `<frame>`s outside of a `<frameset>`?  Have you tried using an `<iframe>` instead?

Comment: Yes, #home is the frameset. I cannot use iframe because I need communication between them.

Comment: You can communicate between iframes with [`window.postMessage()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage) which I think works in IE8.

Comment: Both [`frame`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/obsolete.html#frame) and [`frameset`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/obsolete.html#frameset) are obsolete.

Comment: I know it's obsolete, but you can still find webs using it in Production environments, and they must be maintained.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After one day of research and no responses I was convinced there was no solution for this issue.

But finally I've come up with a solution that solves the problem:

When working with `<frameset>` and `<frame>`, you need to apply a rows attribute to the frameset in order to display the frames correctly within it. **You must edit this attribute before stablishing the SRC param of the new frame!**

The HTML:

```
<frameset name="home" rows="95,*">
  <frame name="frame1" src="/menu.html"/>
  <frame name="frame2" src="/main.html"/>
</frameset>
```

Adding a new frame using JS (for IE8 too):

```
var newFrame = document.createElement("frame");
newFrame.id = "myNewFrame";
newFrame.name = "myNewFrame";
var domFrameset = document.getElementById("home");
if (domFrameset) {
    domFramset.rows = "95,*,100"; //<-- This is the key
    domFrameset.appendChild(newFrame);
    newFrame.src = "/myRelativeUrl.html";  //<-- Set SRC after appending    
}
```

Hope this can help someone suffering same problem-